# How to check and correct misspelling in the data of pairs of words?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, data-cleaning, preprocessing

I have user generated text containing names of ports often containing typos and the actual port names. I would like to correct the misspelling of user generated text containing the names of ports. Can anyone help me think of some ideas or steps to take?
Perhaps using word2vec? RNN?

thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Another way to reframe the problem is [approximate/fuzzy string matching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Approximate_string_matching). [FuzzyWuzzy](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/fuzzywuzzy) is an approximate/fuzzy string matching package for Python. The package can find the nearest element in a set to a user's inputted value with a level of confidence. Something like this:

```
from fuzzywuzzy import process

ports = {"Houston", "New York", "Newark", "Long Beach"}
user_input = "Strong Beach"
best_guess = process.extractOne(user_input, ports)
print(f"The best match for '{user_input}' is '{best_guess[0]}' which is a {best_guess[1]}% match.")
```

> The best match for 'Strong Beach' is 'Long Beach' which is a 82% match.

Answer (score 0):

Spell checking is not really in the realm of train-and-predict models in data science. Mainly because embeddings require known words in the case of word2vec/GloVe, known contexts in the case of doc2vec or known stems in the case of Fasttext plus a significantly large training dataset. Spell checking is instead more traditional software engineering. It's broad but fortunately, you can start small and increase it bit by bit.

If words are commonly known i.e. common nouns and pronouns you can use a package similar to [autocorrect in Python](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/autocorrect) but if you are looking for a specific list of words, in your case ports which are proper nouns, you must use a real spell check procedure. Since it's a broad topic you should start by following the answer provided by [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13928155/spell-checker-for-python/13938115#13938115) about [Peter Norvig's post](http://norvig.com/spell-correct.html) and start building from there according to your needs.

Comment: why can't I use machine learning techniques to solve this type of issue. For example, what if I train the free-text portnames that have typos and their corresponding target actual port names by the means of RNN so as to build a model. isn't it workable?

Comment: You could but it would go against one of the basic tenets of software development: "to keep it simple". Even if you pull it off by training fasttext embeddings containing word particles and have enough data of multiple common misspellings that could generalize well enough to unseen typos, in the best case scenario, performance of the resulting model will be as good as a hard coded spell-checker or the result of using a package like fuzzywuzzy suggested by the other answer. My suggestion is if it's for production start with fuzzywuzzy/Norvig's but if it's just an experiment then go for it.